# 'expected string or buffer' when using re.match with pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to clean some data from a csv file. I need to make sure that whatever is in the 'Duration' category matches a certain format. This is how I went about that:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

data_path = './ufos.csv'
ufos = pd.read_csv(data_path)

valid_duration = re.compile('^[0-9]+ (seconds|minutes|hours|days)$')
ufos_clean = ufos[valid_duration.match(ufos.Duration)]

ufos_clean.head()
```

This gives me the following error:

```
TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-5ebeaec39a83> in <module>()
      6 
      7 valid_duration = re.compile('^[0-9]+ (seconds|minutes|hours|days)$')
----> 8 ufos_clean = ufos[valid_duration.match(ufos.Duration)]
      9 
     10 ufos_clean.head()

TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

I used a similar method to clean data before without the regular expressions. What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

MaxU got me the closest, but what ended up working was:

```
valid_duration_RE = '^[0-9]+ (seconds|minutes|hours|days)$'
ufos_clean = ufos
ufos_clean = ufos_clean[ufos.Duration.str.contains(valid_duration_RE)]
```

There's probably a lot of redundancy in there, I'm pretty new to python, but it worked.

Comment: And what is `ufos.Duration` ? Type: `type(ufos.Duration)`

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> That would be the problem. I'm going to try to use `ufos.Duration.apply(str)` to cast it and see if that works

Comment: So that method of casting didn't work. `ufos.Duration` to a string?

Answer (score 1):

You can use vectorized [.str.match()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.match.html) method:

```
valid_duration_RE = '^[0-9]+ (seconds|minutes|hours|days)$'
ufos_clean = ufos[ufos.Duration.str.contains(valid_duration_RE)]
```

Comment: @i., yes, thank you! I didn't notice `.str.match()` got deprecated

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want it the other way round (not tested):

```
import re
import pandas as pd

data_path = './ufos.csv'
ufos = pd.read_csv(data_path)

def cleanit(val):
    # your regex solution here
    pass

ufos['ufos_clean'] = ufos['Duration'].apply(cleanit)
```

After all, `ufos` is a `DataFrame`.

Comment: I don't quite follow this solution. I'm trying to create a new cleaned `DataFrame` called `ufos_clean` that only contains the rows where `Duration` is in a valid format. I'm not trying to add something new to the existing `DataFrame`